# Click of <input type="file"> is forbidden in WebKit?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webkit

I would like to beatify the `input type="file"` (**A**), and I put another button **B** with *CSS*. When I click **B**, I call `A.click()` for browsing files.

It works well in *Desktop-Web browser*, like *IE8+*, *Google Chrome* and *Safari*. However, when An **Android** app inserted with a `webview`, the `click` event won't be called. (I tried this in **IOS** APP inserted with `UIWebView`, and it works well).

I found an article, https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/File-dialogs. It shows that:

> In `WebKit`, certain operations are forbidden in javascript, for
>   example, you can not generate a click event on `<input type='file' />`, and you can not set/get real values from it.

Since `webview` in **android** is based on `webkit`, how to beatify the `input type="file"` properly?

Comment: why you not applied css to (A) ?

Comment: any idea to apply *CSS* to **<input type="file" multiple="mutiple" id="trueBtn" onchange="previewImage(this)">** ?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-file-input-styling-webkitblink/ try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
<label for="id_of_your_input">any html styles or text, just label tag</label>
<input type="file" id="id_of_your_input" name="name" style="display: none">
```

It should work :)

You really can't simulate click on input file, due security restriction.